# How to refer to glob expanded file name in bash?

Tags: bash

Looking for a general solution to referring to glob expanded file names.

suppose I have 2 existing files. `a.txt` and `b.txt`, each containing the word `hello`.

Is it possible to do a 1 liner to replace `hello` with `world` across both files and overwrite them? `a.txt` and `b.txt` should all contain `world`.

Not sure how to refer to the expanded file names.

`cat *.txt | sed 's/hello/world/g' > expandedFileName`

What should I put in place of `expandedFileName`?

I want to overwrite the existing original file.

Comment: Perhaps something like `for F in *.txt; do echo "$F"; cat "$F" | sed 's/hello/world/g'; done > expandedFileName`?

Comment: sorry about the confusion, but the `expandedFileName` in this case should be `$F`, I want to overwrite the existing file.

Comment: `sed 's/hello/world/g' *.txt`?

Comment: `perl -pi -e 's/hello/world/g' a.txt b.txt`?

Comment: @Cyrus The OP seems to want to use your command with the `-i` switch.

Comment: @Cyrus thank you, `sed` indeed work here, but curious about the general case of referring to the glob expanded file name without loop if possible.

Comment: There can be several globs in a pipeline, how should the shell know which one should be used as the "expandedFileName"?

Comment: @choroba Thank you! I think that's the right answer. It's not possible.

Comment: Note that using `>` to send output to the same file you're reading as input will erase the file. See ["Why does the command shuf file > file leave an empty file, but similar commands do not?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110490/why-does-the-command-shuf-file-file-leave-an-empty-file-but-similar-commands)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tool like `ed` to edit the files you're interested in in-place:

```sh
for file in [ab].txt; do
    printf '%s\n' 'g/hello/s/hello/world/g' w | ed -s "$file"
done
```

will change every occurrence of `hello` to `world` in `a.txt` and `b.txt` and save the changed files.

Or using `perl` and its in-place editing mode:

```sh
perl -pi -e 's/hello/world/g' [ab].txt
```

Some versions of `sed` also support an `-i` option for in-place editing, but it's non-standard and whether or not it takes a mandatory or optional argument depends on the implementation, so I don't recommend it for a general solution.